# Enable serial system console in runtime

Tags: console, linux-kernel, serial-port

There is Linux kernel boot option to enable system console, the `console=`, for example, `console=ttyS0,115200` or `console=ttyS0,115200n8`
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re01.html

After passing this option, linux kernel will print all (or some) kernel messages to the console, which is useful for debugging.

Is there a way of changing system console in Linux in runtime, without rebooting (with some special sysctls/ioctls/or in `/proc` or `/sys` filesystems)?

First case: I had no `console=` option in current booting (checked in /proc/cmdline) and I want to enable dmesg printing to /dev/ttyS0 serial port to debug the situation.

Second case: I had wrong settings in my `console=ttyS0,9600` and want to change speed without reboot (remove old console setting, add new console with good 115200 setting; or just change speed).

(Where `console=` option is parsed, where in `/sys` or `/proc` current settings are stored?)

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I would love to have an answer.

Comment: @jdizzle, I had some ideas of searching for special files of console in `/sys` fs (and for searching in linux kernel source), but I did not get this question to the full answer yet. We should check https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/console/console.txt https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt. netconsole may be enabled in runtime - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo agetty ttyUSB0 115200
sudo password:
ctrl+z
bg
disown
```

If you dont use disown terminal will be closed and also agetty will terminate (SIGHUP signal when closing terminal).

From another PC you can log in using `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`. Login/Password prompt will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full real hardware console added in runtime, but something better for some cases: meet a "netconsole". It is kernel console emulation over udp in Ethernet networks, one-way, only for collecting kernel logs. No more usb-uart adapters or null-modem cables or overpriced com-over-ethernet ["console server"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_server#Console_server) devices. And no more transmit (You may want to use classic kernel console to send [magic SysRq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), but not with netconsole).

Documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt

Examples:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Netconsole

Netconsole should be enabled (or built as module) in the kernel configuration to work. (Sometimes it may be possible to build netconsole module for running kernel and modprobe it into linux without reboot).

To enable with linux command line (with reboot), add:

```
netconsole=[src-port]@[src-ip]/[<dev>],[tgt-port]@<tgt-ip>/[tgt-macaddr]
```

Everything need to be specified: source udp port, source ipv4 address, network interface name like "eth0" (will it work with udev renaming the eth0 into something position-related?), target udp port and ipv4, and also target macaddress in format of six bytes 00:13:32:20:r9:a5.

Receiver is `nc -u -l $tgt_port`.

Example of runtime configuration from the Arch wiki - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole

> ```
> # set log level for kernel messages
> dmesg -n 8
>
> modprobe configfs
> modprobe netconsole
> mount none -t configfs /sys/kernel/config
>
> # 'netconsole' dir is auto created if the module is loaded 
> mkdir /sys/kernel/config/netconsole/target1
> cd /sys/kernel/config/netconsole/target1
>
> # set local IP address
> echo 192.168.0.111 > local_ip
> # set destination IP address
> echo 192.168.0.17 > remote_ip
> # set local network device name (find it trough ifconfig, examples: eth0, eno1, wlan0)
> echo eno1 > dev_name
> # find destination MAC address
> arping -I $(cat dev_name) $(cat remote_ip) -f | grep -o ..:..:..:..:..:.. > remote_mac
>
> echo 1 > enabled
> ```